# Vertical scrollbar in chrome seems to cut off the content slightly at the end

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, scrollbar

I am running into an issue in chrome. When a scrollbar is generated the end of the content is chopped off.

[image]

My relevant css for the outermost div is:

```
#outer-div-id {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 0px 60px 10px 60px;
    width: 900px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: lightgrey;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Firefox seems to be working - so does Opera. For now, if someone can suggest how to fix it in Chrome, it would be superb!

Thank you!

Comment: A "hacky" workaround I found is to add an empty div right after the final textarea:

Comment: Could the textarea or one of its ancestors by chance have a negative margin-bottom?

Comment: You need to provide a link to a live sample or more information about the surrounding html elements and their css in order to get a definite answer. There's not information with which to help you at the moment.